# EXTJS Filefield Reset

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there any way we can reset Filefield once submit form?

I tried

```
Form.reset()
```

or

```
Ext.getCmp('fileupload').reset();
```

and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Form in your case has the **form** xtype. In that case you need tot get the actual form first, as otherwise you would call .reset() on the panel instead of the form:

```
Form.getForm().reset()
```